# How to add a string into set() wiithout it breaking the string up?

Tags: python, set

```
new_set = set('Hello')
```

I want just {'Hello'} instead of each individual character as a part of the set

Comment: Hell, you got 3 different ways of doing it - ain't Stackoverflow wonderful ? ;)

Comment: yes it is! really quickly as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the set and add items to it later on:

```
new_set = set()
new_set.add('Hello')
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a set literal:

```
new_set = {'hello'}
```

Answer (score 5):

The set constructor expects an iterable, and it'll add each item of the iterable to the set. Strings are iterable. Hence, each letter of the string is added to the set.

That being said, do this instead:

```
new_set = set(['Hello'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways with timings (using python 2.7.8 on Windows 7):

Literal:

```
my_set = {"Hello"}
```

Using timeit:

```
python -m timeit "s = {'Hello'}"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0819 usec per loop
```

Empty Set:

```
my_set = set()
my_set.add("Hello")
```

Using timeit:

```
python -m timeit "s = set()" "s.add('Hello')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.222 usec per loop
```

Cast an iterable as a set:

```
my_set = set(("Hello",)) # Equivalent to line below
my_set = set(["Hello"]) # Equivalent to line above
```

Using timeit:

```
python -m timeit "s = set(('Hello',))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.237 usec per loop
```

Comment: The goal was to show which one is fastest (in cases where speed matters). Additionally, I wrote my answer in the time it took the other three answers to come in, so I figured I should add something to make it less redundant.

Comment: because of the way the question is cast, if you really wanted to test their speed, I would just give the possible methods and say which one is the fastest.